# WANem doesn't boot after install

Tags: networking, vmware-esx, boot, linux-kernel, knoppix

I'm using WANem live cd (based on knoppix) to perform network bandwidth tests. In order to keep the current configuration, I've installed it on hard disk (using the gui installation tool provided since v3) on VMWare ESX. The installation ended up normaly.
But during the boot sequence, it's stucked at "Booting Kernel". Do you have any idea of what sort of problem it can be and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue.  I finally found a post that solved the problem.  Build the VM with IDE disk instead of SCSI.  Works fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinstalling, if you installed using SCSI on vSphere 6+ you can use the vSphere Web Client and Edit Settings on the VM, expand the Hard Disk, and change "Virtual Device Node" to IDE0 - IDE(0:0).  Boots fine after that.  You could do the same thing by manually editing the .vmx file for the VM.